# How I can generate a file.sol from ABI?

Tags: truffle

I have created an smart contract but the code in the sol file have disappeared. But the jeson file  still remains.
Can I generate my smartcontract again from ABI ?

Answer (score 1):

You can't.

The ABI is not the full contract, it doesn't know what exactly each function does.
Consider these simple contracts:

```
contract Test {
    uint public num;

    function setNum(uint myNum) public {
        num = myNum;
    }
}
```

And

```
contract Test {
    uint public num;

    function setNum(uint myNum) public {
        //do nothing;
    }
}
```

They both have the very same ABI:

```
[{
    "constant": true,
    "inputs": [],
    "name": "num",
    "outputs": [{
        "name": "",
        "type": "uint256"
    }],
    "payable": false,
    "stateMutability": "view",
    "type": "function"
}, {
    "constant": false,
    "inputs": [{
        "name": "myNum",
        "type": "uint256"
    }],
    "name": "setNum",
    "outputs": [],
    "payable": false,
    "stateMutability": "nonpayable",
    "type": "function"
}]
```

Note that the ABI is just an interface, so it only cares about the "form" of things. It cares about which functions exist and what are their types and parameters; whether they return values or not; what are the public variables and constants, and so on.

Sorry you lost your contract, but it's impossible to generate it from its ABI.